# Ошибка в коде printf (java)

Tags: java, printf

Всем привет! Я новичок в JAVA программирование, помогите найти ошибку.

Подчеркивается `printf`:

```
System.out.ПРИНТФ("Поток %s спит %d", name, time); 
System.out.ПРИНТФ("Поток %s Проснулся и закончился", name);
```

код

```
import java.util.*;

class pussy implements Runnable{


        int time;
        String name;
        Random r = new Random();

        public pussy(String name){
            this.name = name;
            time = r.nextInt(999);
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("Поток %s спит %d", name, time);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(time);
                }catch(Exception e){}
            System.out.printf("Поток %s Проснулся и закончился", name);
    }


}
```

Comment: А все сообщение об ошибке не выложите? А то подчеркивает printf как-то ничего конкретного не говорит.

Comment: если в java обязательна ссылка на класс при указании свойства (`this.name`), то проблема в неинициализрованном `name`, больше там нечему падать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `println` (принтЭлЭн) вместо `printf`. А вообще, вот правильный код [(результат выполнения)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsnZJ.png):

```
public class Pussy implements Runnable
{
    public int time = 0;
    public String name = "";
    public Random random;

    public Pussy(String _name)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        random = new Random();
        time = random.nextInt(999);
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.printf("Поток %s спит %d \n", name, time);
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.printf("Поток %s проснулся и закончился", name);
    }
}
```

Comment: А чем printf плох?

Comment: А чем println плох?)

Comment: Я в том смысле, что у него наверное не в самом вызове printf ошибка, тут явно не хватает сообщения компилятора для определения истинной причины

Comment: А ещё имена классов пишутся с большой буквы!

Comment: Спасибо!!!Очень благодарен. )))

Comment: тут кажется была проблема не в printf а в `@Override`

Comment: Override необязателен, но полезен. Проблема может быть только в шибко умной IDE, которой пользуется автор вопроса.